# Updating existing nullable column to non-nullable in db EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I added a new column to table using :

```
AddColumn("dbo.XYZ", "abc", c => c.Boolean());
```

Model:

```
public class XYZ{
    public bool? abc {get; set;}
}
```

This added a new nullable bit column abc to XYZ.

Now I want to Alter the column to non-nullable boolean with default value false.
So I tried this:

```
 AlterColumn("dbo.XYZ", "abc", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false,defaultValue:false));
```

Model changes:

```
public class XYZ {
    public bool abc{ get; set; }
}
```

On running update-database, I get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'abc', table 'dbo.XYZ';
>   column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I actually want to update existing null records with default value.

Comment: You have to first update all the null values to false first, and then run your AlterColumns.

Comment: @FrankerZ is correct, check the db column for any existing NULL values

Comment: I concur, either manually update the values so they are all not null with a query, or write it in the migration